# Reactive method to combine property in list to single observable

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive

We are struggling to find an appropriate method to combine a property value from a list of elements into a single observable element. Here is some sample code (simplified):

```cs
public class Result {
  public ISubject<bool> Completed { get; }
}

public void SignalWhenAllIsDone(){
  List<Result> list = GetListOfResults(); //not important

  // somehow merge the list and the Completed property into a single observable
  IObservable<bool> allCompleted = ???;

  allCompleted.Subscribe(x => {
    Console.WriteLine("all results have completed");
  });  
}
```

We think that there is some magic in the reactive toolbox that can subscribe to all the `Completed` subjects and merge/evaluate/condense it into a single observable that we can use. We have been doing some manual bookkeeping but our instincts tell us that this is something reactive can assist with.

Any help?

Comment: I think `Result` here looks very strange. It has a `Completed`property that is presumably final when it is set to true, but it is exposed as an observable. Why would your `Result` notify of `Completed` but then later notify `Completed` again with a `false` value (or `true` yet again for that mattter).

Comment: @AlexanderHøst not sure I follow? Maybe I'm not using proper reactive terms? Basically, we are modelling a series of background tasks that at some point will complete. Instead of manually checking that everything is done, we are looking at getting a single observable that notifies when all `Result` instances have completed and e.g. tie UI elements up to this new `allCompleted` observable. The `Result`class obviously has more fields, this is just a simplified example.

Comment: Well, then Result should just have a bool. IObservable is meant for a stream of data and you just want Result to say “I’m done” once. It sounds to me like what you really want is for SignalWhenAllIsDone to be async, and then apply Task.WhenAll to combine results from the background threads (although a bit hard to say without more details).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all of the extension methods for combining Observables provide an overload where they take an IEnumerable<IObservable<T>>. This should fit your requirements:

```
IObservable<bool> allCompleted = Observable.CombineLatest(
              list.Select(res => res.Completed),
              completedValuesList => completedValuesList.All(isCompleted => isCompleted);
```

As an extension to this answer I want to inform you about [DynamicData](https://github.com/reactiveui/DynamicData). With this you could also write a query against a special List that gives you a valid allCompleted-Observable even when the List changes.